# Ant Design: Why are customized form components automatically validated as successful?

Tags: reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

I've noticed that [customized form components](https://ant.design/components/form/#components-form-demo-customized-form-controls) are automatically rendered with the `has-success` attribute. Why is this? Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

By default, errors are not shown and when a user submits the form, validation happens. But if you want `has-error` classes in all fields with invalid data, simply call `this.props.form.validateFields()` in `componentDidMount` method which will run validation and will add css classes to fields according to rules.

Comment: This is an answer to a question that wasn't asked. The class attribute of a standard form field is `class="ant-form-item-control"`. However, the class attribute of customized form field is `class="ant-form-item-control has-success"`. Why are customized form fields being pre-validated as `has-success`? How do I fix/prevent this?